# waterfall chart in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to find if ExtJs has waterfall chart. If yes, Please share the links of examples or demos. I have searched on this and found somewhere just written that EXTJS 3 did have that feature but didn't find the code to do this.

Please share the links.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure it does/had a waterfall chart in 3.3 and I don't think it has one in ExtJS4 to be honest, the API certainly doesn't list one in its chart types.

This plugin for jQuery has a waterfall chart listed if it's any help: http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/cmsfiles/assets/File/charts.html

Answer (score 0):

Below Link will give you all the api details on extjs

http://api.adooxen.com/api/extjs3.3/

Comment: yeah, i have visited the link but as i am beginner in ExtJs, I am not aware of the waterfall chart API, So, Could you please help me with exact information related to waterfall chart.  Thanks a lot!!